# What function would map the set of natural numbers to the set of natural numbers excluding multiples of 2 and 3?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

This question is concerned only with natural numbers. Assume you have a set $x=[0,1,2,3,4,...,n]$ for an arbitrary limit $n$ or $m$ (such that the cardinality is the same) which maps to $y=[1,2,3,4,...,m]$. Then a function that does the mapping is obviously $y=f(x)=x+1$. If you change $y$ so it only has odd numbers, i.e. $x=[1,3,5,7,...n]$ then the function would be $y=f(x)=2x+1$. What would be function that skips multiples of 2 and 3, i.e. $x=[0,1,2,3,4,...,n]$ and $y=[1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,...,m]$ ?

Comment: I'm unsure that I am understanding you correctly.  This comment is more to verify my understanding than it is to provide an answer.  It looks you want all numbers excluded except those numbers that fit in the pattern $(6k \pm 1)$.  If I understand correctly, you could send the even #'s to $(6k+1)$ and the odd #'s to $(6k-1).$  Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: For $k ~\in ~\mathbb{Z^+}, f(2k-1) = (6k-1)$ and $f(2k) = (6k+1)$.

Comment: Your first example fails because $f(n)$ does not exist.  If you want you mappings to be bijections there is none between sets of different cardinality.  Otherwise, you just need to specify $f(n)$

Comment: How about $f(n)=3+6\lfloor n/2\rfloor+2(-1)^{n+1}$?

Comment: or $f(n)=3n+\frac32-\frac12(-1)^n$?

Comment: @RossMillikan Very interesting rebuttal.  In fact, my comments were intended to check my interpretation.  In possible rebuttal, the OP exampled: mapping $x = [1,3,5,7,...,n]$ by $f(x) = (2x + 1).$  Have I misunderstood; wouldn't your objection to my mapping also apply to the OP's offered sample mapping?

Comment: @user2661923:  no, I was objecting to OP's mapping.  Yours is fine because you are using infinite sets and never "run of the end".

Comment: @RossMillikan fixed, assume the cardinality of the sets are equal

Comment: https://oeis.org/A007310

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that set $y$ can be written as

$$y=\{6(0)+1,6(1)-1,6(1)+1,6(2)-1,6(2)+1,6(3)-1,6(3)+1,...\}$$

So first we need a function that maps $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...\} \to \{0,1,1,2,2,3,3,...\}$; that could be either

$$\left \lfloor \dfrac{x+1}{2} \right \rfloor \quad \text{or} \quad \left \lceil \dfrac{x}{2} \right \rceil$$

Next we need a function that maps $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...\} \to \{1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,...\}$; that would be

$$(-1)^n$$

Thus the required function (at least two versions of it) could be

$$y=6\left \lfloor \dfrac{x+1}{2} \right \rfloor + (-1)^x \qquad \text{or} \qquad 6\left \lceil \dfrac{x}{2} \right \rceil + (-1)^x$$

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what the inverse function would be, specifically considering the ceil?

Comment: Actually, the surprisingly simple $y = \lfloor \frac{x}{3} \rfloor $ works; I really would have expected it would require something at least a little more complex. If you need to use the ceiling function, a slight modification will do it: $y = \lceil \frac{x-3}{3} \rceil $

Comment: How did you figure that out?

Comment: Just by inspection. The original function is somewhat close to multiplying by 3, so dividing by 3 seemed natural to try; I'd expected it would need some additional tweaking but it turned out not to. I'm guessing you're looking for a more systematic way to derive the inverse, if there is such a way I can't see it at the moment, sorry.

Comment: No that's perfect, I was just curious because floor/ciel don't have inverses but I hadn't tried inspection.

Comment: Do you know what function would translate an arbitrary number $A$ units? I tried $f(x+A)=6 \lceil \frac{x+A}{2} \rceil+(-1)^{x+A}$ but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what numbers you are attempting to translate. If you're trying to find a function that maps, as one example, $\{0,1,2,3,...\} \to \{11,13,17,19,...\}$, then $y=6\left \lceil \dfrac{x+3}{2} \right \rceil + (-1)^{x+3}$ **will** work.

Comment: Just to have a link, I asked a follow up to this question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988199/does-a-function-exist-that-maps-the-natural-numbers-to-the-natural-numbers-exclu

Answer (score 0):

The function you have list seems to add $4$ then $2$ then $4$ then $2$ and repeats.

so that adds $6$ every other term.

If $n$ is even then $f(n) = 6\frac n2+ 1=3n + 1$

And the next term it adds $4$.  So if $n=2m+1$ is odd then $f(n) = 6\frac {n-1}2+1 + 4=3n+2$

So the function you wrote was $f(n) =\begin{cases} 3n + 1&n\text{ is even}\\3n+2&\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$.

The issues are 1) does that skip all multiples of $2$ and $3$? and 2) does it "hit" everything else?

It's if $x = 2m$ is even then $f(n)= 3n+1=6m+1$ is odd and is not a multiple of $3$.  And if $x = 2m+1$ is odd then $f(n) = 3n+2 = 6m+5$ is odd and not a multiple of $3$.  So, yes, the function skips all multiples of $2$ and $3$.

And does it hit everything else?  Take any natural number $k$.  If you divide $k$ by $6$, $k$ will have a remainder.  If the remainder is $0,2,$ or $4$ then $k$ is a mulitple of $2$.  If the remainder is $0$ or $3$ then $k$ is a multiple of $3$.  So if $k$ is not a multiple of $2$ or $3$ it will have a remainder of $1$ or $5$.

If $k = 6m + 1$ then then $f(2m) = 3*2m + 1 = 6m + 1 =k$.  And if $k = 6m + 5$ then $f(2m+1) = 3(2m+1) + 2 = 6m + 5 = k$.  So, yes, the function hits every number that isn't a multiple of $2$ or $3$.