# Does a function exist that maps the natural numbers to the natural numbers excluding multiples of 2 and 3 and starting at an arbitrary point?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

This question is a [generalization of this other question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3848146/what-function-would-map-the-set-of-natural-numbers-to-the-set-of-natural-numbers) To recap, I was looking for a function that mapped the set of natural numbers to the set of natural numbers excluding multiples of 2 or 3 or both. So a function $f: x \mapsto y$ where $x = \{0, 1, 2, 3,...,m\}$ and $y=\{1,5,7,11,13,17,...,n\}$ for some arbitrary limit $m$. @A.J. gave a great solution

$y=\qquad 6\left \lceil \dfrac{x}{2} \right \rceil + (-1)^x$

(**Erratum:** the independent set $y$ should have been $y=\{5,7,11,13,...,n\}$ however since an answer was given for $y=\{1,5,...,n\}$ I didn't want to change the original and the difference is trivial.)

Now I'm wondering about a generalization that allows for the set $y$ to start at an arbitrary point (that is not a multiple of 2 nor 3). For example instead of $x=0$ mapping to $y=1$ it would instead map to $y=5$ and the formula would then be $y=6\left \lceil \dfrac{x+3}{2} \right \rceil + (-1)^{x+3}$ in other words translated 3 units. Or if we wanted $x=0$ to may to $y=41$ then it would be $y=6\left \lceil \dfrac{x+13}{2} \right \rceil + (-1)^{x+13}$. But I only know this because I precomputed the set starting at 1 and translated the number per the number of skipped members. If the number is bigger this would be non-trivial. For example, $101$ is not a multiple of 2 nor 3 so what function would start with $x=0$ mapping to $y=101$ and then continue by skipping multiples of 2 and 3 e.g. $103, 107, 109$.

Is there a generalization for a function that given the "starting point" $a$ that is not a multiple of 2 nor 3, and the parameter $x$, it maps $x=\{0,1,2,3,...,m\}$ to $y$ where each member of $y$ is $\ge$ $a$ and each subsequent term is the next non-multiple of 2 nor 3?

Comment: Do you need a specific function? If you just need the **existence** of a function, the fact that both sets have cardinality $\aleph_0$ suffices.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer yes my goal to get a specific function, but I don't care if it's piecewise etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a map from the natural numbers, consider the function $$f(n)=3n+a-3+D$$ where

$D=1$ if $n$ is even and $a \equiv 1 \bmod 6 $

$D=-1$ if $n$ is even and $a \equiv 5 \bmod 6 $

$D=0$ otherwise.

If $n$ is odd then $f(n)\equiv a \bmod 6$. If $n$ is even then $f(n)\equiv a-3+D \bmod 6$. Thus no $f(n)$ is divisible by $2$ or $3$.

Also, for any positive integer $n$,  $f(n+1)-f(n)=3\pm 1$ and so the sequence $f(n)$ is monotonic increasing with differences of $2$ or $4$. Thus no non-multiple of $2$ and $3$ greater than $a=f(1)$ is omitted and $f$ is the required function.

(For a map from the non-negative integers replace $n$ by $n+1$ in the formulae.)

**A continuous function of $n$**

Although you are only interested in integer values of $n$ it is amusing to extend the function to all $n$ and also to give it as a definition without different cases.

$$f(n)=3n+a-3-\frac{1+\cos n\pi}{\sqrt3}\sin\frac{a+3}{3}\pi.$$

Comment: I like the soft curve when the continuous version is used. Amazing idea! (+1)

Comment: The standard meaning of "natural" number (which you used in the post) is that they are positive integers. So f(1)=a. But you're right if you wanted to use non-negative integers,

Comment: Thanks, I realized my suggestion didn't work so I deleted the comment. But for documentation sake, I was pointing out the first term is one before $a$.

Answer (score 1):

The additional difficulty in starting at an arbitrary $a$ which is not a multiple of $2$ or $3$ is that we have to consider two cases: either $a \equiv 1 \bmod 6$ or $a \equiv 5 \bmod 6$. The first case is just a translation of the solution from the earlier question; to handle the second case, we first consider the base case $\{0,1,2,3,4,...,m\} \longrightarrow \{-1,1,5,7,11,\ldots,n \}$.

[Strictly speaking our base case should use $\{y\} = \{5,7,11,13,17,...,n\}$ since you want $\{y\}$ to be a subset of the natural numbers, but starting at $-1$ will give a slightly simpler formula.]

Using the same approach as last time, we note the set $\{y\}$ can be written as

$$y=\{6(0)-1,6(0)+1,6(1)-1,6(1)+1,6(2)-1,6(2)+1,...\}$$

We first need a function to map $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,...\} \longrightarrow \{0,0,1,1,2,2,...\}$, which could be

$$\left \lfloor \dfrac{x}{2} \right \rfloor \quad \text{or} \quad \left \lceil \dfrac{x-1}{2} \right \rceil$$

Then we need to map $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...\} \longrightarrow \{-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,...\}$, so we use

$$(-1)^{x-1}$$

giving us the functions

$$y=6\left \lfloor \dfrac{x}{2} \right \rfloor + (-1)^{x-1} \qquad \text{or} \qquad 6\left \lceil \dfrac{x-1}{2} \right \rceil + (-1)^{x-1}$$

Now we can find a function for any starting value $a$ by a suitable translation. If $a \equiv 1 \bmod 6$, we can use the function from the earlier question and translate by $a-1$; if $a \equiv 5 \bmod 6$, we use one of the above functions and translate by $a+1$. Thus we have

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
6\left \lceil \dfrac{x}{2} \right \rceil + (-1)^{x} + a-1& \quad a \equiv 1 \bmod 6 \\
\\
6\left \lfloor \dfrac{x}{2} \right \rfloor + (-1)^{x-1} + a+1& \quad a \equiv 5 \bmod 6
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Re: "Strictly speaking our base case should use use $y={5...}$" yes this is true. It was actually a typo/mistake I had, and meant it to be this.